# How to add a new field to mongodb collection and make it unique?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a mongodb collections with several existing data, and now I want to add new field to the same collection at the same time the new field needs to be a unique field.

I'm using nodejs with mongoose.

Following is my current schema.

```
const user = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: { type: string, required: true},
    token: { type: String, required: true }
});
```

And now below is my new schema

```
const user = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: { type: string, required: true},
    token: { type: String, required: true },
    nickname: { type: String, required: true }
});

user.index({ "nickname": 1}, { "unique": true });
```

Since it has existing data when I run the code it gives me below error.

```
E11000 duplicate key error collection: ourcompany.users index: nickname_1 dup key: { : null }
```

I believe when new field is creating it will be filed with null values. Since the new field is unique it is not allowing multiple null values.

I have scene this [document](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-unique/#unique-index-and-missing-field) but I can't understand what steps to follow.
Please enlighten me about the gap I need to fill.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is your mongo version >= 3.2? Your reference "document" is asking instructing you to use something like  `partialFilterExpression: { nickname: { $exists: True } } }` with versions >= 3.2.  Check out [partialFilterExpression](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-partial/#partial-index-with-unique-constraints)

Comment: thanks I will look into this

Answer (score 1):

use `sparse: true` So Make it as

```
    const user = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: { type: string, required: true},
    token: { type: String, required: true },
    nickname: { type: String, required: true,sparse: true }
});
```

Hope it helps!